# FOSRestBundle & JMSSerializer : Wrong Json Response

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

In the same response i get a field as object and a field as Array, how can i correct this ?

**Note** i don't controle the building of my response because i'm using **JMSSerializer**

[image]

[image]

**CODE (Edit 1)**

*\Entity\Profil.php*

```
       class Profil
        {

        ...
        /**
             * Get actualites
             *
             * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
             */
            public function getActualites()
            {
                return $this->actualites;
            }
...
/**
     * Add actualites
     *
     * @param \Genius\ProfileBundle\Entity\Actualite $actualites
     * @return Profil
     */
    public function addActualite(\Genius\ProfileBundle\Entity\Actualite $actualites)
    {
        $this->actualites[] = $actualites;

        return $this;
    }


    ...
    public function __construct()
        {
...         
         $this->actualites = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
...
        }
```

Comment: I need that the actualites field be always an Array

Comment: in order to better answer your question, you have to show some kind of code that you are using.

Comment: where are you returning the JsonResponse?

Comment: @Sehael by `return $this->container->get('genius_profile.actualite.handler')->all($limit, $offset);` tutorial that i m based (to Ref : http://welcometothebundle.com/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-2013-way/)

Comment: and what is in that `all()` function that you are calling?

Comment: @Sehael all must call `return $this->actualites;` but isn't the case !

Comment: @Sehael get look to my edit

Comment: what is in the `add()` method in the class `Genius\ProfileBundle\Handler\actualiteHandler`

Comment: sorry, I meant the `all()` method in the `Genius\ProfileBundle\Handler\actualiteHandler` class

Comment: @Sehael get a list of actualities as array
`/**
     * Get a list of Actualities.
     *
     * @param int $limit  the limit of the result
     * @param int $offset starting from the offset
     *
     * @return array
     */`

Comment: can you post the code please?

Comment: @Sehael code added to my post

Answer (score 3):

The JsonResponse uses json_encode to encode the values.  json_encode by default will convert a php associative array to a json object, and a numerically indexed array will stay as a json array.  See the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for more info on how json_encode works.

My suggestion is to format your php in the way that you want your json.  if you only want arrays in your json, then you should format your php data using only numerically indexed arrays.  if you only want to use objects in your json, then format your php data to only use associative arrays.

Examples:

```
$a = array(1,2,3);
echo json_encode($a); // [1,2,3] array output in json

$b = array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3);
echo json_encode($b); // {a:1,b:2,c:3} object output in json
```

It looks like you are using an ArrayCollection, which is technically an object.  If you want to convert an ArrayCollection to a simple array, the [Doctrine docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html) show you that you can call a `toArray()` method.  So you would do something like this:

```
$arrayValue = $object->getActualites()->toArray();
```

There are a couple other things that you could try, but they might have unwanted side effects.

**solution 1:** 
you could try this in your entity:

```
public function getActualites()
{
    return $this->actualites->toArray();
}
```

That way, whenever this method is called, it would return an array instead of array collection.  This solution would be better than the next.

**Solution 2:**
The other option is to make that variable an array itself.  So in the constructor, you would have this

```
public function __construct()
{       
     $this->actualites = array();
}
```

I haven't tested this solution, I'm not 100% sure if Doctrine *needs* the Array Collection or not, but you could try as a last resort.

Comment: i don't contole the building of my array

Comment: @Abdellah SELASSI: what kind of answer you're looking for then?

Comment: @zerkms an answer that solve my problem :=)

Comment: @Abdellah SELASSI: this answer provides sufficient info to solve it

Comment: @zerkms i don't controle the building of my array because i use the FOSbundle :)

Comment: @Abdellah SELASSI: I see that it's you who is returning the result array. I don't see any reason to not reformat it to satisfy your requirements

Comment: @zerkms i have used array_values function to convert the associative array to a simple array but not worked !`
 `return array_values($this->actualites);`

Comment: @Abdellah SELASSI: "not worked" is not a technical explanation of the issue

Comment: @zerkms have you work with FOSRESTBundle ?

Comment: @Abdellah SELASSI: this question actually is irrelevant to it. But, yes, I have

Comment: @zerkms good :), i m based on this tutorial http://welcometothebundle.com/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-2013-way/ to implement my REST webservice, so can you guid me to the right place when i must do the modification ! .. excuse me :)

Comment: @Abdellah SELASSI updated my answer

Comment: @Sehael i am disturbed.. normally i use service to mapping my handler  with there entity, so that i understund when i call my webservice the setter  is located in the entity, i have tried to parse it into an array but not worked

Comment: @Abdellah SELASSI updated my answer.  If any of these don't work, then I do not know how to help you.

Comment: @Sehael thanks alote for your time .. any one worked .. because i have checked when i delete getters and setters also the constrector the code still work .. i think that the problem is in the FOSRESTBundle