# JMS Serializer dosen't format property

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I making a RESTful app with Symfony2 and FOSRestBundle. FOSRestBundle uses JMS Seriazlizer to serialize data to json format. I have everything working with one little issue.

*This is my Entity class*

```
class Profil
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="secteur", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $secteur;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nomProfil", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $nomProfil;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="actif", type="boolean")
     */
    private $actif;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateFin", type="date")
     */
    private $dateFin;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="orderNumberMTC", type="integer", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $orderNumberMTC;

     /**
      * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"nomProfil"})
      * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
      */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Genius\ProfileBundle\Entity\Societe", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $societe;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Genius\ProfileBundle\Entity\Coordonnees", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $coordonnees;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Genius\ProfileBundle\Entity\Professionnel", mappedBy="profil", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $professionnels;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Genius\ProfileBundle\Entity\Lien", mappedBy="profil",cascade={"persist"}, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $liens;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Genius\ProfileBundle\Entity\Album", mappedBy="profil",cascade={"persist"}, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $albums;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Genius\ProfileBundle\Entity\Photo", mappedBy="profil",cascade={"persist"}, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $photos;

   /**    
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Genius\ProfileBundle\Entity\Actualite", mappedBy="profil",cascade={"persist"}, cascade={"persist", "remove"})    
    */
    private $actualites;
```

*Controller Action :*

```
 public function getActualitesAction(Request $request, ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
    {
        $offset = $paramFetcher->get('offset');
        $offset = null == $offset ? 0 : $offset;
        $limit = $paramFetcher->get('limit');


        return $this->container->get('genius_profile.actualite.handler')->all($limit, $offset);
        //var_dump($this->container->get('genius_profile.profil.handler')->all($limit, $offset)); die();

    }
```

**genius_profile.actualite.handler IS an ORM**

*and this is json I get:*

[image]

I have tried to force the property `actualitie` to array through the [Annotation Type](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#type)

Any Idea how can i force the property to Array ?

The Report Issue in [github](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/387#issuecomment-42755424)

Comment: @nifr the property `actualitie` is exposed as showing in the screenshot, and as described in the title the problem is the format, i need to force it to be an array

Comment: The property holding the collection gets rendered as a JSON **object** aka `{ property : value}` instead of an **array** aka `[ property : value]` ? Is that your problem ? And what's the difference between the JSON in the lower/upper part of the screenshot ? The profile's JSON if rendered standalone vs the JSON contained in a property of another entity? Please clarify that.

Comment: @nifr yes , https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/387#issuecomment-42755424

Comment: You should've included that github issue in the question :) Where and how exactly do you render the JSON ouput? please add that code to the question. Do all the other properties holding collections always get rendered "correctly" as arrays but only that one property/collection doesn't ?

Comment: Is **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604616/symfony2-type-in-property-genius-profilebundle-entity-profilactualites-was)** of yours basically the same question?

Comment: And **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547419/fosrestbundle-jmsserializer-wrong-json-response)** , too ? Stop posting the same questions over and over again please ... and please don't correct typos that were the cause for issues inside the question next time.

Comment: @nifr  any way the problem still thank you for your remarks

Comment: I had already asked you to provide the code that renders the JSON response i.e. your controller-action. We can't help you without further knowledge ... please improvide the information provided in the question.

Comment: @nifr when i add information they till me .. alote of information when i resume you till me add ... !!!

Comment: @nifr hope the edit is pretty clear

Comment: This controller-action doesn't match either of the 2 JSON outputs you have shown in the screenshot. It's `getActualities()` and returns all actualities. What's the JSON that's being rendered by this url/action now?

Comment: lets continue on chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52532/discussion-between-nifr-and-abdellah-selassi

Comment: Hello Abdellah, i hope you have meanwhile managed to re-design your application to get around this as we discussed in the chat. I just wanted to leave you this little article from OWASP here which explains why returning an object instead of an array might be better in some cases. **[Always return JSON with an Object on the outside](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_AJAX_Security_Guidelines#Always_return_JSON_with_an_Object_on_the_outside)** - happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably filtering your collection somewhere or building it with custom keys, so array's keys are not in sequence (e.g. `[0 => Object, 2 => Object]` without `1` key) so it's serialized as object (representing associative array) instead of array.

You should create virtual property or custom accessor for this field and return collection as `array_values(...)` so keys will be sequenced properly and collection can be serialized as array.